# How to bind array from host to child

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I need to pass arrays as parameters from one tag to another. as you can see in the code im trying to pass users array of objects into child-element tag. But this doesn't work. So how to go about passing array of objects to a nested tag?
**First tag:**

```
  <template>
  </template> 
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "name-tag",
      ready: function() {
      this.user = {{name:"name0",surname:"surname0",age:23},{name:"name1",surname:"surname1",age:15},
      {name:"name2",surname:"surname2",age:65}}
        var toLight = document.createElement('child-element');
        toLight.setAttribute("users", this.user);
        Polymer.dom(this.root).appendChild(toLight);
      }
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>

**Second tag:**
<dom-module id="child-element">

    <template>
      The prop is <h1>{{users.0.age}}</h1> years old
      <h1>{{users.0.surname}}</h1>
</template>

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'child-element',
    properties:{
    users:{type:Object}}
  });
</script>

</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this example for you. I think that you help

```
<dom-module id="element-s">

    <template>
        <child-element data="{{data}}"></child-element>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "element-s",

        ready: function() {
            console.log(this.data);
        },

        properties : {
            data: {
                type: Array,
                value: function () {
                    return [
                        {name: "name0", surname: "surname0", age: 23},
                        {name: "name1", surname: "surname1", age: 23},
                        {name: "name2", surname: "surname2", age: 23}
                    ]
                }
            }
        }

    });
</script>

<dom-module id="child-element">

    <template>
        The prop is <h1>{{data.0.age}}</h1> years old
        <h1>{{data.0.surname}}</h1>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "child-element",

        ready: function() {
            console.log(this.data);
        },



        properties: {
            data : Array
        }

    });
</script>
```